# Is there a Python module for calculating Ovality of a molecule?

Tags: molecular-structure, software, cheminformatics

Ovality gives a measure of how the shape of a molecule approaches a sphere (at one extreme) or a cigar shape (at the other). Ovality is described by a ratio of volume to area (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovality).
So, it is basically "just" about intersecting Van-der-Waals spheres. Although this sounds simple, it can get pretty complicated.

There is a nice paper from M. Petitjean explaining how to get correct values of Van-der-Waals volumes and surfaces (see https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01955983). 
According to this paper, inacceptable approximations have been used in the past.
I can follow this paper to a certain extent, but when it comes to implementing this in Python it would exceed my mathematical and programming knowledge.

Therefore my question:

Is there maybe already a Python module which can calculate Ovality from a given molecular structure? 
Input would be: atom types, atom positions, and Van-der-Waals radii of the atoms.

I'm already using RDKit and maybe it can do it, and I just haven't found this feature.
Thank you for any hints.

I guess there was need for clarification:

The ovality (O), a parameter used as shape descriptor, is defined as the ratio between actual surface and minimum surface for the same volume (the surface of a sphere with a volume that equals the actual volume) (see
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/molecular-size)

For this, the van-der-Waals surface and the van-der-Waals volume of the molecule need to be calculated, basically by intersecting spheres with different sizes at different positions.

Comment: It may be too crude a method, but why not start by calculating moments of inertia assuming all masses are the same. This will give you a prolate or oblate spheroid from which you can get area & volume etc. and is simple to calculate.

Comment: You are looking for the terms oblate (round & flat) and prolate (rugby ball). You usually quantify their shape with the *aspect ratio*.

Comment: @Karl and porphyrin, I would like to calculate the van-der-Waals-surface and the van-der-Waals-volume of a given molecule. How could "moments of inertia" with a crude approximation and the terms "oblate" and "prolate" help me achieving this?

Comment: Because I have never heard the term "ovality", and suspect that you may find other literature with more common search terms, which also don´t exclude the *oblate* part of molecules? *Spheroid* might also be a good search term.

Comment: @Karl, ok, I see. Sorry, I was not aware that "ovality" is not such a common term. I will update the question.

Comment: If I recall correctly, actually, I have found the term "ovality" used more in SAR analysis (in the bioinformatics/drug discovery/ligand design field) rather than in the pure chemical field. By the way I am not able to check it out, but maybe DataWarrior can compute such descriptor :)

Comment: yes, ovality it's a thing in chemistry! check this: https://www.pirika.com/ENG/TCPE/Den-H5.html

Comment: @The_Vinz, thank you for the hint. DataWarrior looks interesting, but I haven't yet found this feature. Even if it has it, it would be cumbersome to integrate it into a Python program.

Comment: Sphere vs cigar, but what about pancakes? (Pancakes are tastier and less damaging to health than cigars .)

Answer (score 2):

I created a python library for estimating the ovality of molecules called [pychemovality](https://github.com/vandan-revanur/pychemovality).

To estimate ovality for a molecule follow the below steps:

```
Clone the repo and cd into root dir:

git clone https://github.com/vandan-revanur/pychemovality 
cd pychemovality
```

Three types of coordinate files can be used as input for calculating ovality.

- XYZ file
- PDB file
- MOL file

To get the ovality of the molecule in your coordinate file run the following:

```
python pychemovality --coord-file-path <path-to-your-coord-file>
```